# Conditional DataGridView to DataTable conversion

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

I've a DataGridView that looks like so:

```
                  DGV 
       | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
```

I was wondering if it is possible to remove the first column when I'm writing to a datatable so that it'll look something like this:

```
             DataTable
        | Col 2 | Col 3 |
```

Additionally, is it possible to eliminate rows that contain a certain value? So if the value is in the datagridview, I want to remove it from my datatable. 
E.g.

```
                  DGV 
       | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
       | Value | One   | Two   |
       | Value | Three | Two   |
       | Value | Four  | Two   |
```

So if there's the value "Three" in the DataGridView, the DataTable would be

```
             DataTable
        | Col 2 | Col 3 |
        | One   | Two   |
        | Four  | Two   |
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I've already tried parsing row by row, but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: @LolCoder I've tried going through row by row. I should've added this but I'm wondering if there's a more efficient (less memory intensive) way to achieve this.

Comment: Check out the answer if it meets your condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, you can do like this to meet your above condition:

```
var dtableDemo = new DataTable();
dtableDemo = this.dgvDemo.DataSource as DataTable; //// Getting the datatable of datagridview datasource
if (dtableDemo != null)
{
    dtableDemo.Columns.RemoveAt(0); //// Removing the first column of derived table

    dtableDemo.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(
               row => row.ItemArray.Contains("put_your_value_to_check")).ToList()
               .ForEach(row => row.Delete()); //// Remove the row if it contains the given value
    dtableDemo.AcceptChanges(); //// Finalize the delete
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a GridView then we copy it to the datatable using

```
System.Data.DataTable GridToDT = new System.Data.DataTable();

            GridToDT = (System.Data.DataTable)MyGrid.DataSource;
```

The corresponding code copies your current gridview to GridToDt Datatable now to remove any column from table what you need to do is find out the index value of the column

```
GridToDT .Columns.RemoveAt(1);
```

or by using Column name as well

```
GridToDT .Columns.Remove("Col 1");
```

And for your other question you could do something like this

```
for(int i = GridToDT .Rows.Count-1; i >= 0; i--)
 {
DataRow dr = GridToDT .Rows[i];
if (dr["Col 2"] == "Three")
    dr.Delete();
 }
```

Hope this helps.Please feel free to mark as your answer if it helps